# How to make MongoClient globaly available in all pages in node js rest API

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have started implementing mongoDB in nodeJS rest API, I saw documentation in mongoDB  official site. This is the code for connection.

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

// Connection URI
const uri =
  "mongodb+srv://sample-hostname:27017/?poolSize=20&writeConcern=majority";

// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(uri);

async function run() {
  try {
    // Connect the client to the server
    await client.connect();

    // Establish and verify connection
    await client.db("admin").command({ ping: 1 });
    console.log("Connected successfully to server");
  } finally {
    // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
    await client.close();
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

How can I make this connection available in all pages of my nodeJS restAPI project.
You can check there github [repo](https://github.com/mongodb-developer/nodejs-quickstart). They have created different files to add, fetch, update data in database.

Comment: imo creating and closing connection on every operation is quite a bad idea.

Comment: This code is written in mongoDB official site. Please check the repo.

Comment: Yes because it's a single use example, which can be interpreted wrong. Usually when you are in production you open one connection per app instance and close it when the instance stops running.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make variable global in node.js you can use the global object, which gives us the scope of the entire project:

```js
global.foo = "bar";
console.log(foo); // Output: "bar"

foo = "john";
console.log(foo); // Output: "john"

foo = undefined;
console.log(foo); // Output: undefined
```

But IMO this is not the best approach in regard of app architecture.